# FedEx rates API does not return both one_rate and weighted packages, despite what their their api documentation says

Tags: rest, fedex

FedEx API documentation states: Note: FedEx customers can request both One Rate and weight based (non-One Rate) rates in a single Rate Request by specifying "FEDEX_ONE_RATE" as a Service Option Type in the request.

https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/rate/v1/docs.html

Where to specify this "Service Option Type" as "FEDEX_ONE_RATE" is never stated, though.  There's  a `variableOptions` property which seemed promising, though as a string or an array with string (the documentation is incorrect about the types of some properties) I get an error about an incorrect value.

> {"transactionId":"5cdab900-959b-4a4a-b5dd-75fd27ad8c86","errors":[{"code":"INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION","message":"Invalid field value in the enum variableOptions"}]}

Currently I only see "one rate" rates and no "weight based" rates when I use the `specialShipmentServices` property.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Is the documentation just wrong?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm so happy someone else posted about this. I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to figure this out. So far I have yet to figure it out. If I find anything I will add a response.

Comment: @HyperTextCoffeePot
Their documentation is a lie, but they have a new "comprehensiverates" api that they're allowing for select customers for beta testing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I appreciate any info on it, we were about to resort to contacting FedEx directly so this saves some headaches.